# go to character in vim

Tags: vim

I'm getting an error message from a python script `at position 21490`.

How can I go to this position in Vim?

Comment: For moving to the nth character in the current line, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466950/go-to-n-th-symbol-in-line

Answer (score 495, accepted):

`:goto 21490` will take you to the 21490th byte in the buffer.

Answer (score 72):

`vim +21490go script.py`

From the command line will open the file and take you to position `21490` in the buffer.

Triggering it from the command line like this allows you to automate a script to parse the exception message and open the file to the problem position.

---

*Excerpt from* `man vim`:

> ```
> +{command}
>
> -c {command}
> ```
>
> `{command}` will be executed after the first file has been read.  `{command}` is interpreted as an Ex command.  If the
>    `{command}` contains spaces it must be  enclosed  in  double  quotes 
>    (this depends on the shell that is used).

Comment: props for recommending automation!