# Go to n-th symbol in line

Tags: vim

How to move cursor to the n-th symbol from the left in Vim?

One of the solutions I see is press `0n<right-arrow>`, it will move to the n+1 position. Is there any more natural way to do it?

Comment: right arrow solution worked for my problem...thnx

Comment: Who ever uses `<right arrow>` instead of `l` in vim?

Comment: The OP proposed solution is simply 1. Got to the beginning of the line (`0`) 2. Run the "Move right" command n times (for instance, `3l` will move right 3 times)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

The pipe '|' character may be what you want:

To go to 25th column in a line in normal mode press `25|`

To go to 37th column in a line in normal mode press `37|`

and so on. . .

Comment: @CamilB Try something like `$3h`, which will move you to the end of the line then 3 characters to the left.

Comment: More on this at vim help `:help bar`. When I found about it it made commenting and uncommentig so much easier XD After discovering this, I do not rely on external comment/uncomment plugins, code-editing life is so much better now :)

Answer (score 49):

EDIT: misread your question.

you can move forward to a particular symbol by typing <kbd>f</kbd> followed by the symbol in question:

if you want to move to the third `$`, you'd type:

```
3f$
```

in order to go backwards, you use capital "F"

```
F$
```

to get to the end of the line first, you use "$"

so your keystrokes for finding the third $ from the end of a line is:

```
$3F$
```

i like to keep something like this handy when using Vim:
http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/vi.html

Comment: This was the first result in google and this was what I was looking for, thank you

Comment: this motion be added to other commands also, like: change from the current position to the 2nd appearance of character "e" - c2te :)

Comment: @Ramy: the link to [lagmonster](http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/vi.html) does not work anymore. Do you know another webpage with similar information? Something like https://linuxhandbook.com/vim-cheat-sheet/?

Comment: if you google for it there are pages all over the interwebs. Here is a pdf you can download and/or print out: https://archive.smashing.media/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/04650c56-ae63-4c1c-8f3c-0cb5f38ebb6b/vi-help-sheet-011.pdf

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if you mean the nth character or nth occurrence of a character; the second has been answered so I will answer the first.

`^` will take you to the start of the line excluding whitespace (so to the first non-white column) and `|` (pipe) or `0` (zero) will take you to the first character. Then `l` (lowercase L) will take you to the right; and `7l` will take you seven characters to the right. So all together, to go to the (n+1)th character on the line, for n=7, `07l`.

Comment: I see you've edited the question now; `l` instead of the right arrow is about the best you'll get.  (are you familiar with hjkl navigation?)

Comment: I know that true vimmer should not use arrows but I use some other applications that do not support low-level key binding and the only way to navigate are arrows, so to make it easier to switch between them I use arrows

Comment: @Vetal: I occasionally get frustrated when scrolling just doesn't work in other applications... hjkl are much nicer than the arrows.

Comment: As Herbert Sitz's answer points out, `|` only goes to the first character because the `[count]` defaults to 1 -- it actually goes to the `[count]`th character in the line, so `8|` is like `07l` except it's a single movement instead of two.

Comment: I think I should pay attention to what characters do.  Should have thought it improbable that there be two ways of doing the same thing.