# "Error: socket hang up" with Express

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, express, io

Node keeps quitting on me when a client refreshes while still loading a page (so the socket gets terminated, while I am still processing the request). The error:

```
[ERROR] - Error: socket hang up
   at createHangUpError (http.js:1472:15)
   at Socket.socketCloseListener (http.js:1522:23)
   at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
   at TCP.close (net.js:465:12) (at lib/Maintenance.js:38)
```

I tried attaching `on('error', ...` to:

1. `req` objects
2. The return value of `listen` (I am using Express)
3. The return value of my `get`, `use` and `post` methods.

And yet, I cannot seem to catch that error; it still gets thrown and none of my error handlers react. What could I possibly be missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Attach error listeners to the socket objects

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.socket.on("error", function() {

    });
    res.socket.on("error", function() {

    });
    next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it in a few. What is the appropriate action to take? Can I just ignore it, or do I somehow have to somehow stop all actions on the `req` object?

Comment: @Domi correct thing would be to stop any processing you were doing for this particular req/res

Comment: This seems so treacherous... Is there not a default solution to this? Like prepend every operation like so: `if (!req.errored) req.doSomething`? Or should `http` not have that build into all of `Request`'s methods?

Comment: Thanks btw, the socket error handlers are actually required. I ended up using [longjohn](https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn), as recommended in [How to debug a socket hang up error in NodeJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814481/how-to-debug-a-socket-hang-up-error-in-nodejs). Turns out, the error was thrown because I did not add an error listener to my instance of [http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy).

Comment: @Esailija but why twice?

Comment: @shabunc twice? i only see one event handler per obj (req vs res)

Answer (score 1):

try catching error like this and see if it works..

```
app.use(function(err,req, res, next) {
    if(err)console.log(err);
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it hanged due to an error during jwt verify wasn't properly managed.

```
return res.status(403)   // issues code
return res.status(403).send(error)  // working code
```