# Nodejs Socket hang up & ECONNRESET - HTTP post request from Meteor to Node js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, meteor

I am using a node server to handle all my push notifications services like gcm and apn.

I have 2 different servers. One is running Meteor and another is running Node.JS to handle push notifications. (Both are different servers)

My main app runs on the Meteor server.

I make an HTTP post request to the node.js server to send my notifications.

Usually it works fine, but sometimes on the Meteor server I get this error whenever I call the node.js server:

```
socket hang up\n    at Object.Future.wait (/home/myPc/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (packages/meteor/helpers.js:119:1)\n    at Object.HTTP.call (packages/meteorhacks_kadira/lib/hijack/http.js:10:1)\n    at Object.sendPushNotificationsMeteorServer (server/pushNotifications.js:249:1)\n    at server/classes/pushNotifications.js:244:1\n    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)\n    at packages/meteor/timers.js:6:1\n    at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:110:1)\n    - - - - -\n    at createHangUpError (http.js:1473:15)\n    at Socket.socketOnEnd [as onend] (http.js:1569:23)\n    at Socket.g (events.js:180:16)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:117:20)\n    at _stream_readable.js:944:16\n    at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)',
details: { [Error: socket hang up] stack: [Getter] },
data: { [Error: socket hang up] stack: [Getter] },
user: null,
userId: null,
toString: [Function] },
user: null,
userId: null,
toString: [Function] }
```

**OR**

```
 Error: read ECONNRESET
     at Object.Future.wait (/home/mbm/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.12ml1tp++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
     at Object.call (packages/meteor/helpers.js:119:1)
     at Object.sendHttpCall (server/pushNotifications.js:249:1)
     at server/pushNotifications.js:244:1
     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
     at packages/meteor/timers.js:6:1
     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:110:1)
     - - - - -
     at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
     at TCP.onread (net.js:559:19)
```

Here is my Node.JS server code:

```
realFs                = require('fs');
var gracefulFs        = require('graceful-fs');
gracefulFs.gracefulify(realFs);

var http              = require('http');
var express           = require('express');
var app               = express();

var path              = require("path");

configClass           = require('./classes/config.js').configClass;
helperClass           = require('./classes/helper.js').helperClass;
pushNotificationClass = require('./classes/pushNotification.js').pushNotificationClass;

var hostname          = 'http://localhost'; 
var port              = 6000;

var bodyParser        = require('body-parser');

nodeGcm               = require('node-gcm');
apn                   = require('apn');
apnService            = new apn.Connection(helperClass.getAPNOptions());

// -- BODY PARSER -- //
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {

  console.error(err);
  console.log("Node NOT Exiting...");
});

// All post requests
app.post('/', function(req, res){

  try {

    var response = JSON.parse(req.body.pushNotificationApiParams);
    var callType = req.body.callType;

    switch (callType) {
        case 'systemPushNotifications':
            return pushNotificationClass.sendPushNotificationsV2(response);
        break;
    } 
  }
  catch(e){

    console.dir(e.stack);
    realFs.appendFile('errorLogs/'+helperClass.getCurrentDateFormated()+'.log', helperClass.formatLog('Exception in main Post Method  : '+e.stack) , function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  }

  res.send("OK");
});



app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Listening at '+hostname+':'+port);
});
```

And here is my code from Meteor side, where I am make HTTP post request to node js server:

```
var headers = {
   'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};

var postFields = {
   callType : 'systemPushNotifications',
   pushNotificationApiParams  : JSON.stringify(pushNotificationApiParams)   // contains push notifications data                 
};

HTTP.call("POST", 'http://localhost:6000', { params:postFields, headers:headers });
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction? Also I would really appreciate to know some good practices as well.

**Also**

There is one more issue I am facing. My node.js server exits after like 24 hours. I don't know why does that happens. It exits without any error or exception in the terminal console. I have to restart it each time.

Comment: Are both servers on the same machine?

Comment: @jannis No they are different servers

Comment: You should consider a network issue then (something in between - e.g. an overloaded gateway/proxy - resetting the connection). I'd set up tcp monitoring on both sides and try to reproduce the issue. Then as it occurs I'd check the logs to see if it's really the nodejs server party that is breaking the connection. This will tell you where to look further - the network or the server itself. I'd bet on the network as this is quite random as you say.

Answer (score 13):

Considering the ***ECONNRESET*** error usually occurs when the *other side of the `TCP connection` is closed abruptly.

- In case of your application
  it may be due to the *`overloading` of the server and simply kills the connection as a return which in the similar way blocks the connection to your `meteor server`*

To get more info about the error as mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814481/how-to-debug-a-socket-hang-up-error-in-nodejs/11542134#11542134).
To handle the error you must use an `event listener` to it to show the full `stack traces` of it

As mentioned in this thread by [*Farid Nouri Neshat*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774086/farid-nouri-neshat)

> To have one listener for a group of calls you can use domains and also catch other errors on runtime. Make sure each async operation related to http(Server/Client) is in different [domain](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#domain_domain) context comparing to the other parts of the code, the domain will automatically listen to the error events and will propagate it to it's own handler. So you only listen to that handler and get the error data.

but since the domain have already been deprecated you should use clusters as mentioned here in the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) which uses `server.listen(message)` and the `server.listen(handle)`

or you can also use `NODE_DEBUG=net` or use [strace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174942/how-should-strace-be-used)

**Update**

For the *server disconnect* i think the error might be in your *handling of the `bodyparser`*.For a *bad* `json` file the *error is uncaught*.

> Node's default action following an uncaught exception is to **exit(crash)** on the process.

Handling of bodyparser for a json file can be done in the following way.

```
var parseJson = bodyPaser.json();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    req.getBody = function (callback) {
        parseJson(req, res,function (err) {
          callback(err, req.body);
        });
    };
    next();
});
```

*Reference taken from the GITHUB open issue's [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/122)*

**Update 2**

Basically the `socket hangup` means that the *socket doesn't end the connection within the specified time period*

According to the [source](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/ba048e72b02e17f0c73e0dcb7d37e76a03327c5a/lib/_http_client.js#L164) you can see that it occurs *if the server never sends the response*

.This error should be caught and handled by either

- retrying to the request.
- handling it later by setting more `time period` or put `res.end()` at the *end of your function* to end the connection.
- or you can use the `[http.get()][8]` with the `get` requests which will automatically call the `req.end()` function

Hope it might help you a bit! Cheers!

Comment: Also there is one more issue I am facing. My nodejs server exits after like 24 hours. I dont know why does that happens.. It exits without any error or exception in the terminal console.

Comment: kindly specify which platform you are using,and any other things which might be necessary,i'll try to look into it

Comment: Both servers are hosted on Linux OS. The NodeJs server is just handling the push notifications. The code which confuse me is that res.end('thanks'); part. I assume my response is not returned sometimes, since this is totally an async operation, so it might not return acknowledgment sometimes, or the acknowledgment is delayed sometimes. thats what I feel

Comment: I am setting 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' & also I am sending the data in params in HTTP request call. It that the right way?

Comment: I'm not too much *pro* with the `meteor` but i can tell one thing that you need to provide  *callback*  to it since the request is `asynchronous` in the format `Meteor.http.call("GET",url,function(error,answer){
     console.log(anwer.answer1);
});` and also to get the log of the error. _The other feature stays the same,you can append the data to it,as_ `json`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the issue myself here. Its in the node server code. I put return in a switch statement which is not a valid way to return a response in express, so I just removed the return from:

**Before:**

```
switch (callType) {
   case 'systemPushNotifications':
      return pushNotificationClass.sendPushNotificationsV2(response);
   break;
}
```

**Now:**

```
switch (callType) {
   case 'systemPushNotifications':
      pushNotificationClass.sendPushNotificationsV2(response);
   break;
}
```

The above `return` was terminating the code before the: `res.send("OK");`

Comment: this is not even close to the solution of the problem you suggested, the problem still exists, but i think **@Pritish Vaidya** approach could help others who have the same problem