# Error: Node Socket hang up only on my machine

Tags: node.js, request-promise

it seems weird that I always have socket hang up on my machine while on the other machine request works well.

even I only request to google.com in order to test it but still got socket hang up. anyone know why this happen? its really frustrating

I write simple to test.

[image]

and after run it. this will intermittently happen

[image]

Well tried on other machine with same code and it works well.

Comment: Post your code. You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @RussellB i have posted screenshos :)

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814481/how-to-debug-a-socket-hang-up-error-in-nodejs/11542134

Comment: @Jonathan im asking why this only happened to my machine. even with same node version. im using 11.1.0. my other machine can run it very well.

Comment: Have you compared the configs of the other machine in which your code runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is working now, seems like there's firewall that block my request into interal system. thanks.