# Find defective line based on error message log for Google big query

Tags: mysql, csv, google-bigquery

I just started working with Google Big query, I am currently trying to uplad some data from my company's DB to Google Big query MySQL table using `bq load` with log enabled. Many of the uploads failed and this is an example of the errors I am getting:

`"message": "Too many values in row starting at position: 394092154."`

I am trying to fix the files manually and the error message is quiet clear and concise, but I need to know how to find the exact line of the error based on the position mentioned in the error message.

I couldn't find much in google documentations, I hope it is only from lack of search effort on my side, but did anyone come across this before, how is this calculation done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[go to character in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543738/go-to-character-in-vim)

I guess I was too eager to get an answer posting the question, but this solved my issue. I found the line based on this.